# Loading Steelseries JAR file to Swing palette

Tags: java, swing, steelseries

I just started using NetBeans for a project of mine, and I needed a gauge in my GUI. I came across the [Steelseries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/steelseries/info) which looks really promising, and downloaded this JAR file:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/DownloadSteelSeries3926jar.htm

I created a Java Project, added the Library to it, and added the Swing palette.
Some beans like `Lightbulb`, `Led`, and `TrafficLight` work fine; but when I choose a gauge, I get this error:

> "Cannot load component class eu.hansolo.steelseries.extras.Radar from
>   JAR file. The class itself was found, but there was a problem
>   initializing it, e.g. due to an exception in static initializer, or
>   failure in loading an additional class needed by the component class."

The exception stack trace follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pushingpixels/trident/ease/TimelineEase
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator$5.run(MetaComponentCreator.java:1450)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.doEventAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.readAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.LazyMutexImplementation.readAccess(LazyMutexImplementation.java:94)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:250)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.prepareClass(MetaComponentCreator.java:1446)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.precreateVisualComponent(MetaComponentCreator.java:258)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.precreateVisualComponent(MetaComponentCreator.java:298)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.HandleLayer$NewComponentDrag.init(HandleLayer.java:3369)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.HandleLayer$NewComponentDrag.<init>(HandleLayer.java:3361)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.HandleLayer$NewComponentDropListener.dragEnter(HandleLayer.java:3658)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.dragEnter(DropTarget.java:358)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processEnterMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:331)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEnterEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:799)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:767)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4746)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4676)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackDropTargetEnterExit(Container.java:4625)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4638)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4591)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4461)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pushingpixels.trident.ease.TimelineEase
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO].Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Comment: Copy the **text** inside the dialog rather than post a screenshot! Then [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38432526/edit) to include that text.

Comment: Needs more [trident](https://kenai.com/projects/steelseries/sources/trunk/show/SteelSeries/lib?rev=109).

Comment: @trashgod I downloaded the trident.jar and added it to the libraries, now it's working!Thank you! Do you also know why the Steelseries library is missing those needed moduls?

Comment: @Evo: Glad you got it working; I've tried to elaborate below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SteelSeries`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/steelseries/info), originally hosted on [`Kenai`](https://kenai.com/projects/steelseries), has moved to [`GitHub`](https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Swing). The project depends on the [`Trident`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trident/info) library, as seen [here](https://kenai.com/projects/steelseries/sources/trunk/show/SteelSeries/lib?rev=109) and in the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Swing/blob/master/pom.xml).

> Do you also know why the `Steelseries` library is missing those needed modules?

The [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/DownloadSteelSeries3926jar.htm) you mention cites pre-built JAR files, each of which excludes the dependent `lib` directory seen [here](https://kenai.com/projects/steelseries/sources/trunk/show/SteelSeries/lib?rev=109) or the artifact reference cited [here](https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Swing/blob/master/pom.xml). The exact approach you take going forward will depend on your [software configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) plan.

Comment: Also consider `DialPlot`, part of [tag:jfreechart], seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20dialplot).